# Getting compass blueprint and sass to work in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blueprint-css, compass-sass

I have setup a new project and used compass to generate the blueprint style sheets. I now have the following code in my screen.scss

```
body.bp {
  @include blueprint-typography(true);
  @include blueprint-utilities;
  @include blueprint-debug;
  @include blueprint-interaction;

    $font-color: #C6C6C6;
}
```

The font in my document does not change however. Using just `color:#C6C6C6;` works fine. What am I missing here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$font-color is a variable, not the color specification itself, so it should be something like this:

```
$font-color: #C6C6C6;

body.bp {
  @include blueprint-typography(true);
  @include blueprint-utilities;
  @include blueprint-debug;
  @include blueprint-interaction;

  color: $font-color;
}
```